# Can I remove whole package system?

Tags: apt, package-management

Yes, I want to **remove whole `apt-xxx` related stuff**, how can I archive it?

Comment: Just, because I am interested: Why do you like to do this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/722102/could-i-remove-apt-with-apt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but this would be a very bad idea.

If you run:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'apt.*'
```

`apt` would show the warning:

```
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
```

But again you can perform the operation as the lower level tasks will be done by `dpkg`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove apt` would be safer, `sudo apt-get remove 'apt.*'` may remove also unwanted stuff (for example `aptitude` if you have it installed, etc)

Comment: I want to remove `aptitude` also, so that is ok.

Comment: @kos check [op's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751822/can-i-remove-whole-package-system/751825?noredirect=1#comment1121291_751825)

Comment: @naive231 Then you should clarify that in the question. But anyway I wouldn't advice removing packages using wildcards / regexes *before* having checked what the result would be, unless you like living on the edge. [List of packages starting with "apt"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=apt), now those are all related to APT / `aptitude`, but would you bet you don't have packages starting with "apt" installed from a PPA or that this won't change? Generally, that's bad practice.

Comment: @naive231 If my answer helped, please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is the package manager, the tool that removes packages. Don't remove that otherwise you wont be able to remove anything.

To remove packages from the terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

As an example

Comment: I know how to remove a package, what I want is remove package system itself, and I know what result it is. So may you hint some directions?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Your system is pretty much useless after that. You could uninstall ubuntu and install an OS that doesn't use apt, maybe suse or something.

Comment: In fact, we want to build a closed, read-only system for stability. we don't want user install any package. That's why I want to do.

Comment: @naive231 don't give them sudo rights?

Comment: No, our goal is no any account system, user is `root` after boot into system. So they don't need `sudo`. :)